# How to subscript an array of strings

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of strings.

```
var questions = ["is it green?", "is it square?", "Where can you find it"]
```

And I need to access it's values. SKLabelNode shows random value of it. And I need to check if it is a right value to give right possible answers. However, if I try this:

```
if questions[0] {
print("0")
}
```

It says "cannot subscript a value of type String". I also tried to name every value, like

```
let first = questions[0]
```

And so on. How to do it right way?

Comment: The error message you provided is incorrect. It produces `cannot subscript a value of type '[String]'`, not `...of type String`.

Comment: okay, I posted it how I remember it

Comment: You need to do a valid comparison in your if. Swift is strict when it expects bools in comparisons. A non-zero value will NOT evaluate to true unlike, say, C++.

Comment: The indexOf method from the provided answer will return nil when the question doesn't exist. EDIT: This comment doesn't make any sense now because the author deleted the comment right under my first comment here. I'm leaving this comment here to see if it ever helps someone. To the author, please avoid deleting your content here. Your question was valid and it could have helped someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let indexOfAnswer = questions.indexOf(randomValue)
print(indexOfAnswer)
```

Comment: So it prints. But I can't access it. Error is on `if questions[0]` line

Comment: I updated, but it should be obvious to make a new object. Now you can access indexOfAnswer.

Comment: I thought it's in-built feature and I can do it just passing it's index. Well, it works, thanks!

Comment: `if` statements look for a Bool (true/false). You provided it with a string (`questions[0]`). If you want to do it that way, it would be `if questions[0] == randomValue`.